# Invalid image POST request JAVA

Tags: java, php, post

I try to upload an image file with POST request and get the following response from server:

```
Notice: Undefined index: width in /home/api.webbankir.com/methods/photo.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: width in /home/api.webbankir.com/methods/photo.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: height in /home/api.webbankir.com/methods/photo.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: height in /home/api.webbankir.com/methods/photo.php on line 37

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid image: 
/home/api.webbankir.com/tmp/d9864480da25e440ff4d591498881e79.jpg' in 
/home/api.webbankir.com/include/Simpleimage.php:1081
Stack trace:#0 /home/api.webbankir.com/include/Simpleimage.php(512): SimpleImage->get_meta_data()
#1/home/api.webbankir.com/methods/photo.php(97): SimpleImage-
>load('/home/api.webba...')
#2 /home/api.webbankir.com/methods/photo.php(411): Photo->load(Array)
#3 {main}thrown in /home/api.webbankir.com/include/Simpleimage.php on line 1081
```

Here is my JAVA code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int  bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;

try {

   connection = null;
    URL url = new URL(url_link);
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setUseCaches(false);

   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

   connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
   connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
   connection.setRequestProperty("file", "img_webbankir.jpeg");

   outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
   outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
   outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + "img_webbankir.jpeg" +"\""  + lineEnd);    /* img_webbankir.jpeg */
   outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

int dimension = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, dimension, dimension);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
b = baos.toByteArray();
imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
outputStream.writeBytes(imageEncoded);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
// Responses from the server (code and message)

int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
Log.e("log", "response code = " + serverResponseCode);
Log.e("log", "response message = " + serverResponseMessage);

outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
Log.e("log", "out put stream closed");


BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
     }
bufferedReader.close();
response = stringBuilder.toString();
connection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Log", "error " + e);
        }
```

I've tried the same request using OkHttp but got the same response...
I've also tried different ways of encoding the bitmap...

Will be grateful for help

Answer (score 0):

Your client is in Java but error messages are from PHP. Therefore, it is server issue. Or you are not using server API properly. Are you integrating with 3-rd party, documented API or with your own PHP server?

If with your own server, you can debug the issue.
If we 3rd party API you should check their documentation if you are using API properly.

PS 
for java rest client there are better, higher level tools than HttpURLConnection. Consider using https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html from spring.

https://github.com/square/okhttp or http://square.github.io/retrofit/ are also good choices. Your client code will be much shorter (2-5 lines, not 70), you will work on higher level of abstraction.

To reproduce the problem, please reproduce same post request with tools like Postman.  https://www.getpostman.com/ 
That will rule out posibility of bug in your java code.

Comment: I'm integrating with documented API. My colleagues - PHP programmers say that API works stably... I guess the problem is related to image encoding because GET requests to the same API methods work properly

Comment: ' API works stably. 'well, your colleagues are extrapolating the truth:). Because there is server error.